Designing circuit parameters with NPN-PNP transistors -LTspice simulation
Below is a part of the circuit I created to drive the MOSFET (it includes level shift, power stage etc.).
Datasheet of 2SC2411K: https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/bipolar/2sc2411k.pdf

Let's start from Q16:
I calculated Ib = 0.7mA, Ic = 130 mA and Vce = 3 V. I see the same values in the simulation. No problems with Q16.
For calculations, I used simple ohm's law and KVL laws around the base-emitter and collector-emitter. I used the hFE value as 185.
Now I have questions regarding Q17 as follows:
I haven't calculated anything about Q17 and I'm examining what will happen to Q17 based on the values I calculated in Q16.
I added some measurements in Figure 2.

The green trace represents the Vce of Q16. 
Blue trace represents Vce of Q17.

Why does Q17's Vce stay around 8.2 V (blue trace) when turned off?

Why does Q17's Vce remain around 0.4 V (blue trace) when conducting?

Looking at the emitter leg of Q17, it turns on the M5 MOSFET. That is, when Q17 is conducting, the emitter leg has no direct contact with GND. If a connection like Q16 was made, Ib, Vce etc. calculations can be easier, but Q17 is different.
Now considering these, how can I calculate the Ib, Ic, Vce values of Q17? What should I pay attention to for Q17? Because when I calculate as in Q16, the values are very wrong.



Please use a white background for the waveforms and please also mention what the green trace represents. The use of net names is much better than leaving net numbers.

Also show your input source numbers and/or a trace. Normally one might want Vce on Q16 to be close to 0V, to get 3V will require an unlikely and unstable balance of gain and input voltage and resistor values.


Why does Q17's Vce stay around 8.2 V (blue trace) when turned off?

First notice that Q17 and Q18 work as an emitter follower (voltage follower), push-pull output stage.
Also for unknown reasons, you have set Vce16 equal to 3V when Q16 is conducting current.
Therefore, if Vce16 is 3V when Q16 is conducting (ON), the voltage at the emitter of Q18 will be around 3.6V (Vbe larger than the voltage at the base).
Thus, Vce17_off = 12V - 3.6V = 8.4V.

Why does Q17's Vce remain around 0.4 V (blue trace) when conducting?

Because Q17 is working as an emitter follower. The emitter voltage will be lower by Vbe than the voltage at the base.
When Q17 is conducting current (Q16 is OFF), the voltage at the emitter will be Ve = 12V - 0.6V = 11.4V therefore Vce17_on = 12V - 11.4V = 0.6V.
The load for Q17 and Q18 is MOS input capacitance. This capacity will be instantly charged/discharged by these two emitter followers and then a very small current will flow for the rest of the cycle. That's why in the simulation Vbe is around 0.4V.

Now considering these, how can I calculate the Ib, Ic, Vce values of Q17? What should I pay attention to for Q17? Because when I calculate as in Q16, the values are very wrong.

No calculations are needed here. But it is a mistake to set Vce16 to 3V.
By doing this you are forcing 3.6V at the M5 gate in a situation where we want M5 to be completely cut-off. Such a high gate voltage can partially turn ON M5 transistor causing a short circuit (shoot-through) with the upper MOS.
But I see that you added a resistor to reduce this short-circuit current.

Thank you so much sir , I understand every point with your help. I have 2 brief questions:  1) I got the point of 3 V at Vce16 so to make it better,  should I reduce Vce16 to a smaller value ?  like a little higher than saturation ?    2) Ic of Q17 is 1.35 A which is much greater than the Ic-max on the datasheet, to reduce it I only need to arrange base current right if no calculation is needed  ? @G36

another question sir if you dont mind : Ib of Q17 also around 60 mA , The reason is as you mensioned above the MOS input capacitances isn't it? because Ib is supposed to be around 0A  with Ve =11.4 V and Vbe=0.6 .   @G36


Q17 should have work in saturation, Try R14 = 1k and R12 = (Vin - 0.7V)/(0.1* 12V/1k) = (Vin - 0.7V)/(0.1 * 12mA) = (Vin-0.7V)/1.2mA.  2) You do not have to worry about it, the BJT will be fine. The average current and average power will kill the BJT. This is not the case here, because in your circuit the average current is very low.   3) Yes, 60mA is due to capacitance load.  And this 60mA impulse of current is very short. This is why the average Vbe is close to 0.4V. Also, what is the point of using M5 and M6? Why can you just drive the M4 gate directly from push-pull stage (Q17, Q18).


Sir I learned a lot from you, thanks a lot. I will be very happy if you can help for my last question. Sir why we didnt consider voltage drop across the R14  for the base of Q17 when it is conducting ?  what I would say for Vb of Q17  is Vb= 12V- (IbxR14) and considering Vbe= Vb-Ve= 0.6 ( or 0.4) , Ve should have been 8.52V . But this doesnt valid here. As you said it is  Ve = 12V - 0.6V = 11.4V but why we didnt considered the voltage drop across R14 ?  may be it is very simple question but ı just wondered it.  @G36

I ignored R14 because you have used a very low value. And the base current is flowing for a very short period of time. Thus, the influence of R14 is very small and hard to notice. But you are right, Vb will be lower by Ib x R14. Or we can say that R14 will be seen at the emitter side as a beta time smaller resistor R = R14/beta .

Thanks alot sir. Every time ı say my last question but whenever I learn someting new another question arise, forgive me for that. If you can help me for another question I would be very happy. Sir, we dont need to calculate Q17 as you said before, I got that. I am just trying to match formulas with simulation . How would you calculate Ib of Q17 with out last values ( which areR14 =1k , Ic=12 mA ....). With our last values the Ib of Q17 is 9mA and Ic=0.7 A and Vce is very low since it is in saturation  @G36

We ignored the voltage drop across R14, I got that as well. But ı couldnt find a way to find this Ib= 9mA of Q17 mathematically. How would you calculate it sir ? @ G36

It is very hard to tell what will be the peak base current. The only thing that we can say for sure is that this base current will not be larger than IB_max = (Vcc - Vbe)/R14
